# Is there a Java Container or collection you can deallocate the size of?

Tags: java

I have a program which stores alot of data in memory currently using Hashmaps.  I'm curious if there is a container or collection in java which I can change the size of the container without copying the contents to another container.  So say I have a Hashmap and its size is 1000 entries.  And i start removing data from the Hashmap.  The size of the Hashmap remains 1000 even though it doesnt contain 1000 entries anymore.  Is there a container out there where I can deallocate the memory used without copying the contents.  The reason I dont want to copy the contents is the data stored is so large attempting to copy the contents to a new container would cause my system to run out of memory.

Comment: _Hashmap remains 1000 even though it doesnt contain 1000 entries_ I don't think this is true. It uses a linked list. Entries are removed when the element is.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis is right, the map's hashtable cannot be reduced, but individual object will be reclaimed at GC if they're not otherwise "alive".

Comment: When i remove entries I dont see my memory go down at all which leads me to think the size allocated to the Hashmap doesnt go down.

Comment: @Jeremy The GC probably just hasn't ran yet.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at how java HashMap works:
http://opreview.blogspot.com/2013/03/how-does-hashmap-work-in-java-hashmap.html
The size is changed when objects are removed however its capacity (the size of the bucket array) remains the same size
You should reconsider usage of HashMap versus ArrayList where you can invoke the method
ArrayList.trimToSize()

Comment: i'm storing to much data to use an Arraylist the searching alone of it would be counter productive.